# Every $.ajax url returns 404 Not Found. What is the correct path? How can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to do a `$.ajax({type: "POST"` to a method found in `\Pages\PCL\PCL_Index.cshtml.cs`. The method signature is `public void OnPostUpdateList(int listId, string itemName, bool isRemoving)`. My attempts always return: `POST https://localhost:44360/PCL/OnPostUpdateList 404 (Not Found)` or some variety of that 404 message. Here is my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/PCL/OnPostUpdateList",
        data: { listId: listId, itemName: itemName, isRemoving: isRemovingChecked },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                console.log(result);
            }
            else {
                alert("Error: " + result.errorMessage);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
```

And here are the url: paths I've tried:

```
url: "/PCL/OnPostUpdateList",
url: "PCL/OnPostUpdateList",
url: "/PCL/UpdateList",
url: "/OnPostUpdateList",
url: "/PCL/?handler=OnPostUpdateList",
url: "/PCL/?handler=UpdateList",
url: "/PCL/PCL_Index?handler=UpdateList",
url: "/PCL/PCL_Index?handler=OnPostUpdateList",
url: '@Url.Page("PCL/UpdateList")',
url: '@Url.Page("PCL/OnPostUpdateList")',
url: '@Url.Page("/PCL/PCL_Index/OnPostUpdateList", "listId", "item", "action")',
url: '@Url.Page("/PCL/PCL_Index/UpdateList", "listId", "itemName", "isRemoving")',
```

I've added this attribute to my model but it doesn't help: `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]`.

I was able to reach the wrong post method `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()` used to post the entire form, but that is not wanted. That method was reached when I used these:

```
url: '@Url.Action("UpdateList", "PCL_Index")',
url: '@Url.Action("OnPostUpdateList", "PCL_Index")',
```

**How can I best troubleshoot this frustrating issue? What is the correct url path?**

I'm using ASP.Net Core 6 Razor Pages. My goal is to allow users to add or remove items from drop-down select lists on the page (and the underlying database lookup tables). I want to let them modify lists without updating the entire form that the select lists are within. When the user clicks a button next to each select list a bootstrap modal form pops up allowing the user to add or remove list items. The ajax code is called when the user clicks Save Changes on the modal window.

EDIT: I have just found the problem was caused by some information I did not provide since it was overlooked. Within IIS Express I had set up an App URL of `localhost:64373/Lab`. So, I have been missing `Lab/` from my path. In the future I can post a more complete answer, unless someone else would like to try given this new information.

Comment: First o all, your function for the POST is this `public void OnPostUpdateList(int listId, string itemName, bool isRemoving)`  Is your controller called PCL controller ?

Comment: The method is in the PageModel of a Razor Page named PCL_Index. I'm not using MVC and don't have a controller.

Comment: Maybe try passing the action to your form like this: `<form asp-page-action="OnPostUpdateList" method="post">` Have you tried that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to do that because it would post the entire form. My goal is to allow users to add or remove items from drop-down select lists on the page (and the underlying database lookup tables). I want to let them modify lists without updating the entire form that the select lists are within.

Comment: Try that in your AJAX  `url: "/PCL?handler=UpdateList"`

Comment: Thanks, but that also returns: POST https://localhost:44360/PCL?handler=UpdateList 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251433/discussion-between-oris-sin-and-developerdan).

Comment: Appears to have been resolved in the chat using the standard `@Url.Content("~/")` trick.  Please close the question or provide a complete answer.

Comment: I need to leave for the day, but I'll answer it later...unless someone else wants to answer it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using `@Url.Content("~/")`

To troubleshoot this issue, look at the url (of the page) in each location where the application runs. Here, the deployed url is: `https://(Host Name or Domain Name)/PCL`. During development the url is: `https://localhost:(Your Port)/Lab/PCL`. Notice the addition of `/Lab` on the development machine. This App URL is set in the project properties Launch Profiles for IIS Express.

To resolve the different paths to the application root make use of `@Url.Content("~/")`. Unfortunately, javascript does not understand `@Url.Content("~/")` so we build a javascript function called `expandPath`:

```
function expandPath(path) {
    if (!path) return undefined; if (path.substring(0, 2) === "~/") {
        const root = $("body").attr("data-rooturl");
        path = root + path.substring(2);
    } return path;
}
```

which points to the body element of the `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
<body data-rooturl="@Url.Content("~/")">
```

Finally, we call expandPath in the ajax url:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: expandPath("~/PCL?handler=UpdateList"),
        data: { listId: listId, itemName: itemName, isRemoving: isRemovingChecked },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                console.log(result);
            }
            else {
                alert("Error: " + result.errorMessage);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
```

Notice the use of `?handler=UpdateList` to point the method `public void OnPostUpdateList`. `?handler=` is used in the queryString because we want to avoid calling the default `OnPost` method to prevent posting the full page to the server.